# Firefox caches pages since last week

Tags: firefox, http-headers, browser-cache

I am currently in version 80.0.1 (64 bits) under Ubuntu / Linux and since last week Firefox caches the pages of my website!

Result when I log out, I still have the user menu. I add infos in the Top headers and these options are displayed on some pages but not all, I need to do a SHIFT Reload to display the page update.

There were NO worries until last week!

It has become absolutely unusable, for example: I connect to my site and the menu does not appear... I change the currency from € -> $ and the prices do not change on display (Except with a Shift reload).

I have not changed anything in the site code and no problem on other browsers.

The site is written in PHP and I tried to fix the problem by adding these headers at the beginning of each page:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

But even with these Headers options, there is still a cache problem that makes navigation impossible.

Does anyone have a solution?